# How do I effectively release vector memory at the end of the function?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-leaks, c++builder

in my code,I defined an array:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > *line_sep=new std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > [16];
```

in my test,when i use  `delete []line_sep;`i found my computer memory usage is rising slowly.
i just want to release line_sep memory.

16 vectors of pairs!..
exp

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > *line_sep=new std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > [16];
for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<1700;j++){
        if(....)line_sep[i].push_back({Begin,End}); 
    }
}
fun(line_sep);
delete []line_sep;
```

Comment: Memory usage rising slowly means you are not deleting everything.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>`.

Comment: And: 16 vectors of pairs?

Comment: If you want the vector to be deleted at the end of the function don't dynamically allocate it. I think you might be looking for `std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > line_sep(16);`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: use `line_sep[i].emplace_back(Begin,End); ` instead of push_back

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would use `delete[] line_sep;` to free it.  Anything you allocate with `new[]` must be freed with `delete[]`.

However, using another `std::vector` would be preferred instead of using a raw pointer:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> IntPair;
typedef std::vector<IntPair> IntPairVec;

std::vector<IntPairVec> line_sep(16);
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <1700; ++j)
    {
        if (....)
             line_sep[i].push_back(std::make_pair(Begin, End));
    }
}

fun(&line_sep[0]);
```

Or, in C++11 and later, a `std::unique_ptr` would also work:

```
using IntPair = std::pair<int,int>;
using IntPairVec = std::vector<IntPair>;

std::unique_ptr<IntPairVec[]> line_sep(new IntPairVec[16]);
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <1700; ++j)
    {
        if (....)
             line_sep[i].push_back({Begin, End});
    }
}

fun(line_sep.get());
```

Comment: I understand , thank you for your help

Comment: That is the correct solution, if you insist not to put `line_sep` on the stack. But since a `std::vector` is relatively small, you can just write `IntPairVec line_sep[16]`.